# Boto3 s3.get_object_attributes not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to an s3 object meta data from my lambda. According to the boto3 documentation, the best way to do this is using the .get_object_attributes but when I try this I get: 'S3' object has no attribute 'get_object_attributes': AttributeError. The get_object call works fine.

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_client.get_object(Bucket=source_bucket_name, Key=file_name)
s3_client.get_object_attributes(Bucket=source_bucket_name, Key=file_name)
```

Comment: You are probably using a back-level version of boto3. Update to a current version.

Comment: I am running from within lambda

Comment: The version of boto3 packaged with Lambda is a few releases behind the latest boto3 package version. If get_object_attributes was added recently, which I believe it was, then your only option other than to wait, is to [package](https://github.com/jeromevdl/boto3-lambda-layer) the latest boto3 version in a Lambda layer.

Comment: Updated to newest version and still the same.

Comment: No, it won't be the same. Your code will now fail with: `Missing required parameter in input: "ObjectAttributes"` because you haven't included `ObjectAttributes` as a required parameter to your call to `get_object_attributes()`.

Comment: An example of valid parameter is: `ObjectAttributes=["ETag"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to upload the newest verson of botocore and boto3 to lambda.

Answer (score 2):

The get_object_attributes function requires an argument called ObjectAttributes that specifies which attributes it should return.

```
attributes = ['ETag', 'Checksum', 'ObjectParts', 'StorageClass', 'ObjectSize']
s3_client.get_object_attributes(
    Bucket=source_bucket_name,
    Key=file_name,
    ObjectAttributes = attributes)
```

Answer (score 0):

HeadObjectResponse objAttrResp = amazonS3Client.headObject(HeadObjectRequest.builder().bucket(sBucket).key(ticket).build());

by using this response, can get most of the Object meta information and even the custom meta data added by user on the object